# Como obtengo el valor de un registro seleccionado por combobox usando php

Tags: select, combobox

Si alguien tiene respuesta se lo agradeceré mucho. Quiero obtener el valor del registro seleccionado para mostrarlo en el mismo formulario de donde seleccione el registro.

Éste este es mi código:

```
<tr>
   <td scope="row" align="right">Nombre de Carrera:  </td>
   <td> <select name="carrera" onchange="">
   <option value="" selected>Selecciona una carrera</option>

    <?php 

$res=mysql_query($query);

    while($row=mysql_fetch_array($res))
    {
        ?>
            <option value="<?php echo $row['idcarrera'];?>'" selected="true"><?=$row['nombrecarrera']?></option>

    <?php } $idcarrera=$row['idcarrera']?>


    </select></td>
    </td>
  </tr>
```

Comment: celco, tu pregunta es confusa. Puedes elaborarla mejor? No la entiendo.

Comment: @celco, Te refieres a obtener el valor del combo despues de enviar el formulario? Que has probado?

Comment: Ya lo tienes en el mismo formulario, es el valor del propio select, o no es eso? En el mismo formulario tendrias que recogerlo con javascript o jquery, por php tiene que enviarse el valor antes de poder recogerlo

Comment: PHP **se ejecuta en el servidor**. HTML/Javascript **se ejecuta en el cliente/navegador**. Tienes que enviar los datos al servidor, y procesar la respuesta (ya sea enviar todo el formulario y recargar la página, o usar Ajax).

Answer (score 1):

Mi recomendación es que le pongas un id al select, luego tomas el valor con javascript:

```js
var optCarrera = document.getElementById("elemento")
optCarrera.onchange = function(){
  alert(this.value);
}
```

```html
<tr>
   <td scope="row" align="right">Nombre de Carrera:  </td>
   <td> 
      <select name="carrera" onchange="" id="elemento">
        <option value="0">Selecciona una carrera</option>
        <option value="1">Carrera 1</option>
        <option value="2">Carrera 2</option>
        <option value="3">Carrera 3</option>
      </select>
    </td>
  </tr>
```